# iOS: different debug and release constants, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, header-files, compile-time-constant

I'm new to objective-c and ios development and looking for best practice. I want to have different constants `BASE_URL` which is dependant on DEBUG and PRODUCTION environment..

I want it to look like, e.g. **Constants.m**:

```
#import "Constants.h"

static NSString *BASE_URL = @"http://localhost:3000";

NSString * const API_URL = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/api"];
```

and **.pch** file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

But compiler is saying I'm wrong here - `NSString * const API_URL = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/api"];`

**Initializer element is not a compile-time constant**

Comment: Good search @rmaddy, also I would like to add you can't write code in the air. Your error statement should be inside a method, not anywhere in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting is self explanatory: you need to use a compile time constant.

About having different debug and release constants, just use the following:

```
// YourConstants.h
extern NSString * const kYourConstant;

// YourConstants.m
#import "YourConstants.h"

#ifdef DEBUG
NSString * const kYourConstant = @"debugValue";
#else
NSString * const kYourConstant = @"productionValue";
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second line (`NSString * const API_URL = ...`) is correct but must be inside a function or method.